# Valor central de un número con cantidad impar de dígitos

Tags: python, string, variables, basic, estadística

```py
NI= input("Ingrese numero de cantidad impar de cifras (al menos 3 cifras): ")
NT= len(NI)
NC= int(str(NI)[0])
NF= int(str(NI)[-1])
NM= ?
```

No se como sacar el valor de esta variable (tiene que ser el valor central del numero introducido. Ej: `13567`, seria `5`). Estoy buscando una solución parecida a lo que hice en las dos variables de arriba.

```py
print ("El numero ingresado tiene",NT,"cifras.")

print ("La primera cifra es",NC,"la ultima es",NF,"y la central es",NM,end=".")
```

Answer (score 0):

buenas noches ya desde España, he hecho un códgio que a lo mejor te puede ayudar con esta preguta que tienes.

```
numero = int(input("Introduce un número impar: "))if numero % 2 == 0:
print("El número introducido no es impar.")else:
valor_central = numero // 2 + 1
print("El valor central del número introducido es:", valor_central)
```

A ver si cone eso te ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de hacerlo puede ser la siguiente.

Una vez tengas tu número 'n':

```
n = 10267 
s = str(n) # lo pasas a formato string

# El operador // Obtiene el cociente entero de la división
# Lo que hace esta línea es obtener el índice donde se encuentra el número central
m = len(s) // 2


# Ya tenemos el índice ahora obtenemos el número que se encuentra en dicho índice
print(int(s[m])) # Devuelve un valor entero
print(s[m])      # Devuelte un string
```

La salida del ejemplo que he puesto sería `2` pero puedes poner el número impar con tantas cifras como quieras.

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy claro!

Answer (score 0):

En Python, las cadenas se comportan parecido a otros arreglos (listas) así que ya puedes hacer algunas operaciones en ellas directamente:

```py
NI = input("Entre un numero: ") # <-- Ejemplo, "4589627"

n_primero = NI[0]
n_central = NI[len(NI) // 2]
n_final   = NI[-1]

print(n_primero, n_central, n_final) # <-- 4 9 7
```

Pero si lo quieres hacer de forma numérica, sin usar operaciones de cadena, puedes descomponer todo el número en una lista de dígitos y aplicarle la misma lógica. 
[*] Nota: Debido a que la lista empieza recibiendo el último dígito hasta llegar finalmente al primero, entonces estará en orden inverso.

```py
NI = int(input("Entre un numero: ")) # <-- Ejemplo, 4589627 (*) Observar el int()
cifras = []
while NI:
    cifras.append(NI % 10) # Agrega el último dígito a la lista
    NI = NI // 10 # Elimina el último dígito del número

n_primero = cifras[-1] # [*] Ver Nota
n_central = cifras[len(cifras) // 2]
n_final   = cifras[0]

print(n_primero, n_central, n_final) # <-- 4 9 7
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion!. Pude solucionar y entender el problema